# Groupby using 2 different functions syntax

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm using the following statement which works fine to total some columns by Team and Year in an NBA Analytics project.

```
nba_df =pd.DataFrame(bball_data.groupby(['Tm', 'Year'], as_index = False)['BPM_A', 'WORP', 'VORP', 'PER'].sum())
```

I would also like to include Average Age, but can't seem to figure out the syntax.

The following statement would work fine on its own but, only returns the average age, not the other sums:

```
nba_df =pd.DataFrame(bball_data.groupby(['Tm', 'Year'], as_index = False)['Age'].mean())
```

Basically, I need a way to combine the 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
nba_df = pd.DataFrame(bball_data.groupby(['Tm', 'Year'], as_index=False).agg(
    {'BPM_A': 'sum', 'WORP': 'sum', 'VORP': 'sum', 'PER': 'sum', 'Age': 'mean'}))
```